# What is the difference between Win10 and Win11 when trying to get .NET Process Cpu Usage?

Tags: c#, .net, process, cpu-usage

I am trying to get the CPU usage of a given process. In our case, we run a Jar-File.

This is currently how we get the CPU usage.

```cs
private async Task<double> GetCpuUsageForProcess(Process process)
{
  var startTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
  var startCpuUsage = process.TotalProcessorTime;
  await Task.Delay(500);

  var endTime = DateTime.UtcNow;
  var endCpuUsage = Process.GetProcessById(process.Id).TotalProcessorTime;

  var cpuUsedMs = (endCpuUsage - startCpuUsage).TotalMilliseconds;
  var totalMsPassed = (endTime - startTime).TotalMilliseconds;

  var cpuUsageTotal = cpuUsedMs / (Environment.ProcessorCount * totalMsPassed);
  var cpuUsage = cpuUsageTotal * 100;
  return cpuUsage;
}
```

The Code works on another machine which is running Windows 10. However, when we tried it on some Windows 11 Machines, we always got 0, except for some really short durations (But the CPU usage only was about 0.1%).

We are not in Control of what the Jar File actually does.

Comment: How many processors/threads have a machine with Win 10 and Win 11?

Comment: @LukaszSzczygielek These are the used Machines:

Win11: 6 Cores/ 12 Threads (i7 10th), 

Win11: 6 Cores/ 12 Threads (i7 8th), 

Win10: 4 Cores / 8 Threads (i5 11th),

Comment: The resulting value (very small) on Win 10 you divide by 8 and on Win 11 by 12 - hence the difference.